# What could the dough of this cookie be made of?

Tags: baking, dough, cookies

After repeatedly eating what I consider the most delicious cookie I have ever eaten, my wife soon became frustrated trying to replicate it. So I am reaching out to gather ideas. This is the cookie, from a pastry shop. The filling is some kind of soft nougat, but the mysterious part is the cookie itself.

Here are some thoughts:

- We assume that ingredients include (shortbread): flour, butter, and sugar
- We tried icing sugar but it became too sweet
- We tried milk with unclear success (?)
- We tried eggs (white, yolk) but the taste did not match and it became too soft
- The surface is a bit sticky
- The taste is sweet and salty, a bit toasted/burnt which makes it so special

Unfortunately, I was not able to take a picture of a full cookie, so here is it half-eaten, as I could not control myself.

What could the dough be made of?

[image]

Comment: What's the texture of the cookie? You said the surface is a little sticky, but how's the rest of it? Crumbly, chewy, fluffy...?

Comment: What does the bakery call this cookie?

Comment: How big is it? What shape (I presume circular, but is it a flat disc or are the faces rounded)? How thick is it? What country are you in? It's much more likely that it's a specific known type of cookie/biscuit which someone can identify and you can search for recipes of, than that someone here will be able to usefully suggest ingredients based on a single photo. Even with the ingredients known, the method will be just as important.

Comment: Depending on where you live, you might be able to ask them about allergen information, which can help you to eliminate or identify possible ingredients.  It would also be worth knowing more about the pastry shop -- the Vietnamese and Japanese have patisserie, but might use coconut milk or other ingredients that wouldn't likely be used by Europeans.

Comment: @senschen It is *not* soft, it's rather crisp, but when you break it, it breaks slowly, and it melts on the tongue. It's far from fluffy, though.

Comment: @dbmag9 They call it "Swiss", but that did not help me. It is a flat disc, yes. About 5-10mm thick. We live in Germany.

Comment: @Joe We did ask whether they contain nuts, and that was rejected. So no nuts. We also think there are no eggs in them, as eggs fundamentally influence taste.

Comment: I also envisioned something crazy like caramelised milk if that even exists. The roasted flavour is so difficult to describe.

Comment: Diameter is approximately 7-10cm.

Comment: @Cookie : caramelized milk *does* exist.  It's called "dulce de leche" in spanish.  You're also close enough to Belgium that they might be using 'candi sugar', which is caramelized sugar ... but if they had either ingredient, there cookies wouldn't be as pale as they are.  (it's also possible that they're using egg whites as a binder, but not the yolks).  Someone needs to make the cookie equivalent of Identifont.

Comment: Going purely off the picture, location and name, could they be Schweitzer Nusstaler? Click across for images: https://www.google.com/search?q=schweizer+nusstaler

Comment: This product also looks like a plausible candidate: https://images.app.goo.gl/oWVkFYiNBXx9cgKPA

Comment: And as a final suggestion for the flavour you're trying to identify, it could be that brown butter has been used; I've made blondies with brown butter which turn out amazing.

Comment: I wonder if the cookie itself is a kind of tuile or langue de chat (more likely, as tuiles have ground almonds), maybe made with brown sugar which would give it a more caramelized taste. If nuts aren't involved, its unlikely to be a schweitzer nusstaler...

Comment: Wow, so many ideas! Okay, let me sum up: The Schweizer Nusstaler seems to be an unlikely candidate as presumably no nuts are involved. We tried almond paste today and it turned out to be a disaster. I am hearing dulce de leche for the first time, so I will try that definitely; although my wife claims that would taste differently. Tuile does not match as it's with almonds. That "candi sugar" is an unknown term to me. But would they remain so pale, as you stated? "Langue de chat" look very similar (browning on the sides!) but the ingredients seem unobtrusive ...

Comment: And brown butter! Maybe brown butter? Will try. In "Modernist Cuisine at Home" I at some point read about pizza baked in a frying pan, which made me wonder whether the cookie could not be baked at all?! My wife disagrees, though. But why is it so sticky? I need to wash my hands afterwards to ged rid of the stickiness.

Comment: Stickiness can be caused by sugar+moisture. I would imagine that a cookie with a high enough sugar content could become sticky with the addition of moisture, for instance from a filling or from being kept in a humid enough environment (or a combination of the two).

Comment: And re: "the ingredients seem unobtrusive", yes, that's true, but most baking uses the same ingredients-- with just the basics of flour, sugar, eggs, milk, butter you can make an extremely wide variety of baked goods from cookies to cakes to breads and many other things. As noted above, its not necessarily the ingredients that will result in your perfect cookie, its the method/technique with which those ingredients are combined.

Comment: @senschen Could you give an example for how the techniques could differ? I am an amateur baker.

Comment: Consider the differences between a basic cookie (some butter rubbed into flour and sugar, add egg to bring dough together and bake-- this is a very simplified version of something that I make, a proper shortbread would be made the same way with no egg and more butter) and a pound cake (using all equal amounts, butter and sugar creamed together until pale and fluffy, add eggs beating very well after each one, fold in flour, bake). My cookies are soft and chewy, nothing like a pound cake. Likewise with the addition of yeast and kneading, the same ingredients in different proportions make bread.

Comment: As Senschen said, it is rather unlikely that you will be able to reverse-engineer the cookie if you don't know much about baking. You need not just the list of ingredients, but also the ratios and the method. An experienced baker may be able to do it, but that baker will have to taste each experiment and compare it to the original, fine-tuning to eliminate the differences (and even then, there is no guarantee of success). I suspect that you probably don't need any unusual ingredients, just the correct recipe.

Comment: You are right, though, without experience, it might be nearly impossible. Still worth a try :-) Brown butter was delicious and added a nutty taste, seemed like a step into the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a shot in the dark with the minimal information, but I will give it a try.

My best guess is that you already have all the ingredients you need: butter, sugar and flour. What you are missing is probably the ratio. The dark edge with the crisp texture and the nutty flavor is very likely sugar that has self-caramelized in melting butter (similar to the tuille somebody mentioned in comments). Also, the image shows that the cookie is "flowing" - it was not stamped out from a rolled short crust, for example, it was a ball which melted in the oven. And it melted enough that it became very thin, with the edges flowing out to become thinner than the center.

I would suggest that you don't continue trying random recipes, but find a recipe for a cookie of this kind and follow it. You are most likely to find these recipes as recipes for malleable cookies for making e.g. edible ice cream bowls. I don't have my books here, so I can't post the recipe I have (you can come tonight(CET) into chat, if you want) but you can just search for this type of recipe online. Even if you don't find the perfect match, it will probably be a better starting point than random trying.

If you insist on trying yourself though, or cannot find one of these recipes, I would suggest you modify a German shortbread ratio (3-2-1 flour-butter-sugar). Make sure you are using butter, not a margarine or other substitutes, these have different spreading behavior when melting. And then simply reduce the flour substantially, possibly also increase the sugar, and see where that takes you.

Comment: "you can come tonight(CET) into chat, if you want" If the information's relevant to the answer, it should probably be a part of the answer, for posterity's sake, in case anyone else finds this question through Googling.